# Como eliminar duplicados sin peder el orden PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo una tabla la cual dinamicamente, asocio los impuestos con su concepto, pero la consulta me puede retornar varios conceptos e impuestos repetidos, pero al final debo de eliminar los registros respetidos

```
WITH test_data AS
(
  --PRODUCT | VALUE
  --:------ | ----:
  SELECT 125  AS ord, 'Ties' AS product, 'P' AS concept FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 127  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 345  AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 346  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 58   AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 59   AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL  
  SELECT 723  AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 724  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 95   AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 96   AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1102 AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1103 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 366  AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 367  AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1555 AS ord, 'Pants',   'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1556 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1787 AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1788 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 197  AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 198  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual
), 
test_data_extended AS
(
  SELECT product, 
         concept, 
         LAG(product, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS pre_product,ord
  FROM test_data
), 
test_data_new AS
(
  SELECT product AS old_product, 
         concept,
         ord, 
         CASE WHEN product = 'tax' THEN 
              'tax (' || pre_product || ')' 
         ELSE product 
         END AS new_product
  FROM test_data_extended
), 
new_data AS
(
  SELECT UNIQUE ord, 
         new_product, 
         concept
  FROM test_data_new
order by concept
)SELECT * FROM   new_data
```

He encontrado una posible solución, en donde logro eliminar los duplicados pero pierdo el orden, los productos deberia de quedar con su impuesto en la siguiente fila

```
test_data_new AS
(
  SELECT product AS old_product, 
         concept,
         ord, 
         CASE WHEN product = 'tax' THEN 
              'tax (' || pre_product || ')' 
         ELSE product 
         END AS new_product,
         CASE
         CASE WHEN product = 'tax' THEN 
              1
         ELSE 0 
         END AS id_d
  FROM test_data_extended
), 
new_data AS
(
  SELECT UNIQUE ord, 
         new_product, 
         concept,
         id_d
  FROM test_data_new
  order by concept,id_d
)SELECT * FROM   new_data
```

El resultado esperado seria algo similar a esto:

```
 NEW_PRODUCT 
 -----------:
 Shirts      
 tax (Shirts)
 Ties        
 tax (Ties)  
 Pants       
 tax (Pants) 
 Stocks      
 tax (Stocks)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb81654494c74de65036d935e1986c5e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi sugerencia es crear un par de columnas que tengan el producto de referencia y el orden deseado (para que siempre salga el producto antes de su impuesto).

Esto te devuelve el resultado deseado:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
  --PRODUCT | VALUE
  --:------ | ----:
  SELECT 125  AS ord, 'Ties' AS product, 'P' AS concept FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 127  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 345  AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 346  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 58   AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 59   AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL  
  SELECT 723  AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 724  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 95   AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 96   AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1102 AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1103 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 366  AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 367  AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1555 AS ord, 'Pants',   'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1556 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1787 AS ord, 'Stocks',  'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1788 AS ord, 'tax',     'T'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 197  AS ord, 'Shirts',  'P'    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 198  AS ord, 'tax',     'P'    FROM dual
), 
test_data_extended AS
(
SELECT   product
       , concept
       , ord
       , LAG(product, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS pre_product
       , LAG(ord, 1) over (order by ord) as pre_ord
  FROM test_data
), 
test_data_new AS
(
select   case when product = 'tax' then pre_product else product end ref_product
       , case when product = 'tax' then 1 else 0 end prod_order
       , case when product = 'tax' then 'tax (' || pre_product || ')' else product end as new_product
  FROM test_data_extended
), 
new_data AS
(
select distinct 
         ref_product
       , prod_order
       , new_product
  from test_data_new
 order by ref_product, prod_order
)
SELECT new_product 
  FROM new_data;
```

Resultado:

```
new_product
------------
Pants
tax (Pants)
Shirts
tax (Shirts)
Stocks
tax (Stocks)
Ties
tax (Ties)
```

Comment: esta muy genial y facil de comprender mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo como prerequisito que el orden del concepto de impuesto sea siempre consecutivo mayor por una unidad, es decir que si el orden de los pantalones es 43 entonces el orden de su concepto de impuesto es 44, podrías agrupar las descripciones con el máximo ordenamiento de estas y al final ordenar los resultados.

```sql
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT 126  ord, 'Ties'   product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 127  ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 345  ord, 'Stocks' product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 346  ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 58   ord, 'Shirts' product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 59   ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 723  ord, 'Shirts' product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 724  ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 95   ord, 'Shirts' product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 96   ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1102 ord, 'Stocks' product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1103 ord, 'tax'    product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 366  ord, 'Stocks' product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 367  ord, 'tax'    product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1555 ord, 'Pants'  product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1556 ord, 'tax'    product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1787 ord, 'Stocks' product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1788 ord, 'tax'    product, 'T' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 197  ord, 'Shirts' product, 'P' concept FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 198  ord, 'tax'    product, 'P' concept FROM dual
)
SELECT product
FROM   (
    SELECT MAX(a.ord) ord
    ,      a.product||NVL2(b.product, ' ('||b.product||')', NULL) product
    FROM   test_data a
    ,      test_data b
    WHERE  b.ord (+) = a.ord - 1
    GROUP BY a.product||NVL2(b.product, ' ('||b.product||')', NULL)
)
ORDER BY ord;
```